# Tensorflow-gpu cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll not recognised [Error code 193]

Tags: python, tensorflow

When trying to use Tensorflow (gpu), it won't run because of this :

> Could not load library **cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll**. Error code **193** Please make sure **cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dl**l is in your library path!

The thing is, that I have this lib :

[image: path to libs]

and I've added the environnement variables :

[image]

**Full error message** :

> To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2022-01-02 00:22:39.438945: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 5468 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
> 2022-01-02 00:22:40.466945: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5468 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
> 2022-01-02 00:22:41.646700: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1774] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
> 2022-01-02 00:22:41.780145: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8301
> Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193
> Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was simply because I can't read the doc properly...

I installed all the latest versions of CUDA, cuDNN and Tensorflow GPU, but they aren't compatible.

here is what helped me : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

So I installed :

- tensorflow_gpu-**2.6**
- CUDA **11.2**
- cuDNN **8.1**

and guess what, everything works fine now !

So in case of :

> Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126

or

> Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193

Re-install CUDA with the recommended versions and don't forget to update your PATH

Comment: I confirm it's a working combination. I've been suffering from errors and searching for a solution. After installing the exact version, my problem was fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I use CUDA v11.6 and cuDNN v8.4.

I solve it by changing CUDA v11.6 to v11.4 and cuDNN v8.4 to v8.2.4

Here is [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-4-4-download-archive?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local) and [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

Answer (score 0):

My case.
The PATH has been duplicated.

error
PATH=****;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\libnvvp;*****;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\libnvvp;

correct
PATH=****;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\libnvvp;

The cuda installers add path. Duplicated paths often will cause errors.