# error - "I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8400 Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, facenet

I have encounter "I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8400
Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 193"

will working with TensorFlow.
version:
TensorFlow 2.8
CUDA 11.6
CUDNN 8.4

Comment: Can you please try with `CUDA: 11.2` and `cuDNN: 8.1` as recommended [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu). For more details please refer similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70552632/). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer2 how to specify cuDNN version?

Answer (score 1):

The versions you installed for TensorFlow and NVIDIA CUDA probably don't match.
Try using one of the versions tested here: [Tensorflow GPU Source Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)
Don't forget to install "tensorflow-gpu" module instead of "tensorflow" in order to use NVIDIA GPU Acceleration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i simply used conda insted pip to install cuda and cudnn. then used pip for the tensorflow gpu instalation.  vrsions that worked with each other are cuda 11.2 and tensorflow2.10. anything above 2.10 not suport gpu

Comment: `anything above 2.10 not suport gpu` I don't think this is accurate. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu